# jQuery: unwanted behavior of my drop down menu (desktop and mobile)

Tags: javascript, jquery, drop-down-menu, responsive-design

I've built a dropdown with jQuery and some css / scss. It works at first glance, but there are always errors that I think are due to jQuery code or unnecessary CSS rules. I'm just not sure which of them ..

You can see the current status here. The said dropdown menu is the item "Leistungen" in the Navbar:

https://www.s-wat.de

Especially in the mobile viewport errors appear. If I open the dropdown here and in the opened state click on another point (for example "Kontakt") and then on "Leistungen" again, there is an unwanted fadeIn fadeOut effect. The dropdown will open and close first, before I can open it normally.

Here is my jQuery code:

```
(function($) {
    "use strict"; // Start of use strict

    // Closes responsive menu when a scroll trigger link is clicked
    $('.first .js-scroll-trigger, .last .js-scroll-trigger, .dropdown-menu .js-scroll-trigger').click(function() {
      $('.navbar-collapse').collapse('hide');
      if (!$('.dropdown-menu').hasClass('show')) {
        $('.dropdown-menu').fadeOut('slow');
      }
      $('.dropdown-menu').removeClass('show');
      $('.dropdown').removeClass('show');
    });

    var navbarBehave = function(){
      if ($(window).width() < 992){
        $('.dropdown-toggle').click(function() {
          if (!$('.dropdown-menu').hasClass('show')) {
            $('.dropdown-menu').fadeIn('slow');
          }else{
            $('.dropdown-menu').fadeOut('slow');
          }
        }); 
      }else{
        $('.dropdown-toggle').hover(function() {
          if (!$('.dropdown-menu').hasClass('show')) {
            $('.dropdown-menu').fadeIn(300);
          }else{
            $('.dropdown-menu').fadeOut(300);
          }
        });     
      }
    }

    navbarBehave();

    $(window).resize(function(){
      navbarBehave();
    });   

  })(jQuery); // End of use strict
```

Comment: I'm not getting the error, which browser do you use?, in chrome everything works fine, in microsoft edge when opening the dropdown, selecting leistungen and then kontakt, it closes the dropdown and when i open it again, leistungen is still open and when clicked on the first time does nothing, the second time it closes

Comment: @RamondeVries 
I use Chrome, but I also get the same error on Safari and Firefox. Open the menu in the mobile viewport, click on "Leistungen" and then on "Kontakt" without closing the "Leistungen" dropdown. Then open the menu again and click on "Leistungen". There should be a fadeIn fadeOut of the dropdown.

Comment: when i open the menu after i clicked on leistungen and then kontakt, leistungen is still open and won't react to the first time i click it

Comment: Can you check it on mobile Safari? The error that it does not react to the first click, I have unfortunately discovered now. 
But the fadeIn fadeout effect is still there. 
The dropdown should also close when an item within the dropdown is clicked. But this does not always work, but always with repeated attempts.

Comment: well, i can't replicate the problem but, what i think could be the solution is this: instead of using .click, execute the function when the li class="sibling nav-item dropdown" has something like :focus (so when you clicked on it but not when you click somewhere else) execute the function, this makes sure your dropdown will close if you click something else, and not stay open while hidden after you clicked for example Kontakt